# Laravel Insert ID from one table to another

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables `categories` and `product_categories`.

`categories` has `id`, `name` and `product_categories` has `category_id`. How do I fetch `id` from `categories` and put that value to `category_id`?

I tried:

```
Route::get('/categories/create', function() {
    $categories = [
        'Hardwares', 
        'Buldings',
        'Properties',
    ];

    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $productCategories = new ProductCategory;
        $categories = new Category;
        $categories->name = $category;
        $productCategories->category_id = $categories->id;
        $categories->save();
        $productCategories->save();
    }
});
```

Is it possible via one to one relationship? I just tried this in `ProductCategory.php':

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Comment: can a product have multiple categories? or would a product always only have one category?

Comment: Product will have one category.

Comment: having a model called `ProductCategory` doesnt make sense to me. You should have `Category <-- Product`. Category will have a `hasOne()` relationship to Product, and Product a `belongsTo()` to Category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the category before using its attribute ..

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $categories = new Category;
    $categories->name = $category;
    $categories->save();

    $productCategories = new ProductCategory;
    $productCategories ->category_id = $categories->id;
    $productCategories->save();
}
```

Comment: This didn't save all the IDs. It only saves 1, 17, 18, 19, 20, ..and so on. It doesn't save 2 to 16!

Comment: can you show me the complete data structure of the categories you're trying to save ?